# SWIG - include existing static C++ library (.lib) using cygwin

Tags: java, c++, cygwin, swig

I'm currently working on a Java Project which will be added to an existing larger system. The communication with the system is on an XML basis over a network connection.

The Problem is that this system was written in C++ and the library they are offering to us in order to communicate with the system is a C++ based static library (`.lib`). We have the header file of that library, so I was able to generate the `.java` and the corresponding wrapper files using SWIG.

Now the problem I'm facing is how to include this static library in my `.dll` which will be used to receive the JNI calls from the Java program.

How would I need to call gcc to generate a working dll? Is it even possible to do that without access to the sources of the library?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible - when you compile and link the DLL using the wrapper SWIG generates you will need to do something like:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -shared -o test.dll test_wrap.cxx -Wl,--whole-archive some.lib
```

The key thing here is that you're linking the DLL generated by the SWIG wrapped code against the .lib you've got. (I've not used cygwin much, but you might want to add `-mno-cygwin` to the compiler flags in this instance as well, depending on how the .lib was built)